# Помогите построить локатор xpath или css

Tags: css, xpath

Всем привет.

Помогите решить мою проблему).

Не могу найти элемент на странице,если построить локатор таким способом //div[contains(text(),'100')], то находит, но нужно чтоб в локаторе было именно полный текст 
//div[contains(text(),'100 000 ₽')] - так не работает из-за & nbsp;

Как это можно обойти?

Вот пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому поможет в будущем :)

Нашел решение данной проблемы, попробую подробно описать на своем локаторе:

//div[contains(text(),'100(вместо пробела нажимаем клавиши для винды: **ALT + 0160**,
для макОС: **⌥ + ⇧ + SPACE**)000₽')]

выглядеть будет так: //div[contains(text(),'100 000₽')]
и на всякий случай ссылка на таблицу с такими символами [тыц](http://www.typeandglyph.com/)